# java.sql.SQLException: Opening db:'DB-NAME.sqlite' : Permission denied

Tags: java, ubuntu, netbeans, deployment, installation

I had developed a Java Application Project using Netbeans IDE 8.2 on Ubuntu14. How can I have its installers for Linux Systems using Netbeans IDE(.deb) Native Packaging.

I had packaged it by following instruction in [this](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2074947/core-java/native-java-packaging-with-netbeans-7-4.html) link

But, [this](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2074947/core-java/native-java-packaging-with-netbeans-7-4.html) tutorial above mentioned is NetBeans 7.4 native packaging in Windows. But I followed this tutorial in Netbeans8.2 in Ubuntu(my system). And I got .deb file in specified folder in the tutorial mentioned above.

The Project-name-1.0.deb file could be successfully installed in my Ubuntu System, but while running this installed application it shows error: "java.sql.SQLException: Opening db:'DB-NAME.sqlite' : Permission denied"

My project uses sqlite DB for data storage. I had used JAR sqlite-JDBC-3.19.3.jar for its Library.

I had used Netbeans IDE 8.2 in Ubuntu and created the new Java Application Project in it.

Now, how can I package this Java Application project to get its installer for Linux(.deb) without this Permission denied error

The java Connect.java class is as follows

```
import java.sql.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Connect {

    Connection con = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    public static Statement ConnectDB() {
        try {
            Connection conn = null;
            Statement stmt = null;

            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:JavaApp3DB.sqlite");

            stmt = conn.createStatement();

            return stmt;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The application execute successfully in NetBeans without any permission denied error. But, it shows the error when the Packaged (.deb) installer when installed and executed in Ubuntu.

Comment: @NidhinCB - If this is actually your question and you've been locked out of your account for Manu, you should head over to [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) to ask if you can get your accounts merged. Right now it looks like you're adding your code to someone else's question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this `jdbc:sqlite:JavaApp3DB.sqlite` 
to this `jdbc:sqlite:JavaApp3DB.db`

When you want to connect to your database you need an address and this address mention to a file we call `database.db` not `.sqlite`.

Comment: dude when you want to connect to your database you need an address and this address mention to a file we call database.db not .sqlite

Comment: Nice, thank you. Please edit your answer accordingly. It might get an upvote when you do. And it might even get accepted as *the* answer.

Comment: @WhiteDruid- I had changed it to.db. But, this error is not solved. Now it shows "java.sql.SQLException: Opening db:'DB-NAME.db' : Permission denied". It is regardless of data base file name which is created. The packaged Installer file (.deb) for ubuntu which is build from NetBeans, when installed on ubuntu, the corresponding files are created on folder "/opt". So, when the installed application is executed, it try to create "DB-NAME.db" file in the folder "/opt/... " where it might be Permission denied. But, how can it be solved when installers are generated from netbeans.

Comment: bro you should give an addres like this jdbc:sqlite:C:/sqlite/db/yourDataBase.db try this tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_create_database.htm

Comment: Yes, I had given the path to the folder too. It does't solve the issue. The Application execute successfully when run using netbeans, but it (.deb) build packaged from netbeans when installed in ubuntu shows this error. Kindly read my question once again. I had made some correction for better understanding of the issue.

Comment: i searched its about the path you given to the your path

Comment: Yes, I changed the path from "/opt" to "/home" in Ubuntu, where permission is not required. Now popup will not appear while running the application

Comment: have you solve this problem? I am facing the same situation