# Intellij Windows 10 SQLite Access denied

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sqlite, windows-10

This is a Java Project which connect to a sqlite database. I didn't really know where is the problem, I am making a login app to my manager here is my code:

```
package dbUtil;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class dbConnection {
public static final String USERNAME = "dbuser";
public static final String PASSWORD = "dbpassword";
public static final String CONN = "jdbc:mysql:\\localhost/login";
public static final String SQCONN = "jdbc:sqlite:\\dbname.sqlite";

public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException{
    try{
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        return DriverManager.getConnection(SQCONN);
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

And here is the error I found, I didn't know what exactly is happening:

```
java.sql.SQLException: opening db: '\dbname.sqlite': Access is denied
at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.open(CoreConnection.java:203)
at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.<init>(CoreConnection.java:76)
at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.<init>(JDBC3Connection.java:25)
at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:24)
at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.<init>(SQLiteConnection.java:45)
at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:114)
at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:88)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
at dbUtil.dbConnection.getConnection(dbConnection.java:20)
at LoginApp.LoginModel.<init>(LoginModel.java:18)
at LoginApp.LoginController.<init>(LoginController.java:19)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:927)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at LoginApp.LoginApp.start(LoginApp.java:15)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

PS: I found someone's comment but I didn't get what he meant exactly: 
I had created a SQLite database prior to watching this video and I saved it in a different directory. For my project, I didn't create a fresh .sqlite like Awais did in the video. I was exporting my original database to a new .sqlite file using SQLite Studio. This was the problem of why I couldn't log in (1:20:00) to the database. SQLite Studio apparently encrypts the database if you export it into a new database; *so that means that your program can't access its contents*. What I did, was copy my original database that I created, and moved it into the project/src directory. This was my hang up. Awais isn't very clear on how he copied his database to the project directory at the beginning of the video, so I kinda glazed over this step and didn't do it with my database. DO NOT SKIP THIS STEP. Good luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.sql.SQLException: Opening db:'DB-NAME.sqlite' : Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46237315/5221149)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.sql.SQLException: Opening db:'DB-NAME.sqlite' : Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46237315/java-sql-sqlexception-opening-dbdb-name-sqlite-permission-denied)

Comment: I already changed 'dbname.sqlite' by 'dbname.db' but i found the same result.

Comment: @MustaZIR have a look at the directory/folder/file permissions?

Comment: @Rick the SYSTEM has the full control of the file, so this didn't solve my problem yet.